# when i execute the command ./install.sh i get an error saying name resolution doesn't work need help with this

Tags: pi-zero, raspbian-stretch, internet, dns

i can not find any thing to fix this , i have i think tried everything it still gives this error and so i can't install P4wnP1.
I,m using raspbian stretch with desktop as opposed to raspbian jessie lite and stretch lite . [image]

Comment: you either are not connected to the internet or DNS is not setup.

Comment: Looks like your DNS setup is broken. We need more detailed info about your network setup.  
https://github.com/framps/raspberryTools/blob/master/raspiNetInfo.sh collects a lot of network info. Just post the result.

Comment: Maybe the authors of P4wnP1 have duped you... maybe they've just turned your RPi into their 'bot? My advice: drop this.

Comment: Can you try to resolve another DNS name? Try: nslookup raspberrypi.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

Sorry to bother . it turns out it had nothing to do with raspbian , pi 0 w or P4wnP1. but it was my network providers fault who provided me with a faulty DNS which causing the said error. The installation problem was solved when I connected it to 3G network on a friends phone and his wifi. so it was just the network providers issue.

Comment: You can accept your own answer for your question or remove the question (as it's not Raspberry Pi related any more).